# How to handle list of object by jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ajaxq

I was looking out for the way to get list of objects (properties of class) and paste it to the some controls by searching only name .how can I do taht
 I used this snipped:

```
$('#applicant').autocomplete({
            source: '/Home/GetApplicant'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

According jQuery UI documentation

> The datasource is a simple JavaScript array, provided to the widget using the source-option.

I'm attaching you an example.

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

Your input tag has to have the attribute id="tags".

Comment: tnx for your reply but it not my problems . I mean when I searching for specific name . and the server respond me list of object like name , phone ,address, .... how can i get those of that by searching only name and pastins those to the input controls

Answer (score 0):

finally, I will write a custom code to customize a component by using jquery ajax and tables to keep it temporary and click to a specific cell to retrieve complete data so here is all we need to do :
[image]